# LocalStorage Problem - Key not being Created properly - returns null

Tags: javascript

I am having a LocalStorage Problem where it isn’t creating a new LocalStorage Key when the key doesn’t exist.

I have this code:

```
var times = [];
var solves = 0;
if(localStorage.getItem("solvesDone") === null)
{
    alert("Creating a Solves Object")
    localStorage.setItem("solvesDone", 0);
}
else
{
    if(localStorage.getItem("solvesDone") !== null)
    {
        solves = localStorage.getItem("solvesDone");
        localStorage.setItem("solvesDone", JSON.parse(solves));
        solveCount.innerHTML = "Solves: " + solves;
    }
}

if(localStorage.getItem("timesDone") === null)
{
    localStorage.setItem("timesDone", JSON.stringify(times));
}
else
{
    if(localStorage.getItem("timesDone") !== null)
    {
        times = localStorage.getItem("timesDone");
        localStorage.setItem("timesDone", times);
        alert(times);
    }

}
```

Here, it’s not creating the key even if the key doesn’t exist.
I’m trying to make a speedcube timer.
The full website is here of you want to see it: https://speedcube-timer.coderguru.repl.co/
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `localStorage` works for me on your codeguru site. However there seems to be a `NaN` thing going on with your `times`...probably because it's never parsing the string after it reads from localStorage. Perhaps you want to do something like `times = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timesDone'));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected however I did some refactoring. You don't need the deeply nested if condition

```js
var times = [];
var solves = 0;

if(!localStorage.getItem("solvesDone")) {
    alert("Creating a Solves Object")
    localStorage.setItem("solvesDone", 0);
} else {
    solves = localStorage.getItem("solvesDone");
    localStorage.setItem("solvesDone", JSON.parse(solves));
    solveCount.innerHTML = "Solves: " + solves;
}

if(!localStorage.getItem("timesDone")) {
    localStorage.setItem("timesDone", JSON.stringify(times));
} else {
    times = localStorage.getItem("timesDone");
    localStorage.setItem("timesDone", JSON.parse(times));
    alert('times', times);
}
```